# Find input field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to find three inputs (type=text) which were added dynamically using jQuery. I've tried to use `.closest()`, `.parents()`, `.find()`, and `.children()`, but I failed.

I also tried with document.getElementsByName, but it does not return the correct value if I create more than one group of inputs (which can be added dynamically, as I said before).

My code is the following:

```
function update(username, row) {
    affiliation_val = $(document.getElementsByName('affiliation')).val(),
    comments_val = $(document.getElementsByName('comments')).val(),
    role_val = $(document.getElementsByName('role')).val();
//the search above does not work when I add multiple inputs… it returns only the first three inputs 
    console.log( $(row).closest(“input”) ); //one of my attempts... I also did using a combination of parents("tbody") and  children("input"), for example... and many others  
}


function format(d) {
        var message1 = '<table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>User ID:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"> &nbsp; '+username+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>Password last set:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"> &nbsp; '+d.pwd_last_set+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>Uid number:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"> &nbsp; '+d.uid+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>Email:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"> &nbsp; '+d.email+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        split_projects(d.projects_name, d.projects_role),
        message2 = '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>Affiliation:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"><input type="text" name="affiliation" value="'+d.affiliation+'" '+readonly+' /></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>Comments:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"> <input type="text" name="comments" value="'+d.comment+'" '+readonly+' /></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="text-right"><b>Role:</b></td>'+
            '<td class="text-left"><input type="text" name="role" value="'+d.role+'" '+readonly+' /></td>'+
        '</tr>',
        message3 = show_inconsistency(inconsistent)+
        show_miss_uid(miss_uid)+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>&nbsp; </td>' +
        '<td>'+
              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendMail(\'' +username+ '\'); return false">' +
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Request change of permission' +
              '</button> <br/><br/> ' +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
    '</table>',

        button = '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="update(\''+username+'\', this)">Update</button</td></tr>';

    return message1+message2+button+message3;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciate...

Comment: im a little confused by your syntax/structure haha, is what you're trying to do is get all the input values of a given row when you click the button in that row? could we see the html structure (no the one you built in js)

Comment: I updated the code. I hope it will be clear now. I'm creating one table and returning it. Then the user changes the values of the inputs. Once the user clicks on the update button, I want to get the values of the three inputs in this table and work with them at my backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work as your selector, change "role" accordiingly:

```
$( '#tableId input[name="role"]' ).val();
```

Edited after more detail (see comments below)

Comment: This yields to the same problem I had with document.getElementsByName. It returns the value of the first table only

Comment: @rennomarcus If this is working, but you need multiple feilds, just use `each()` e.g. `$( 'input[name="role"]' ).each(function(){ alert($(this).val()) })`

Comment: Ah, ok. Is there any reason you can't give the inputs an id , maybe with the name and the index of the group of inputs (table 1 has role1, table 2 has role2, etc) and use those as the selectors?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't using ID's, because I wasn't sure where to put. But you are right... I can put the userid as the table's id and then do a search. I'll try this approach and update with my results

Comment: That should be perfect, then you can change the above to `$( '#tableId input[name="role"]' )` etc

Comment: It worked flawless now. I did $(tableid).find('input[name="role"]'), but your way looks even easier to read. I will stick with that. If you edit your answer I would like to accept it. Thanks, @MikeSprague

Answer (score 3):

Use the `jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )` selector

```
affiliation_val = $( "input[name='affiliation']" ).val();
comments_val = $( "input[name='comments']" ).val();
role_val = $( "input[name='role']" ).val();
```

Comment: That won't work since it's looking for the value as opposed to the name

Comment: Thanks, I meant to put name instead of value

Comment: Same thing as @MikeSprague 's comment

Answer (score 2):

As also suggested by @DBS, use `.each()`.

```
$('[name="role"]').each(function(index, element){
    console.log( $(element).val() );
});
```

This will loop through every element currently on the page with the name "role" and print their value to the console.

If you only needed to find the elements (to do something else with them, as you suggest in your question), then you can use `element` inside the `.each()` loop to do stuff with each element.

Here's another idea. If you know the parent of the elements (since it sounds like you have more than one of each of these elements on the page), and are interested in a particulare one, try this:

`$('#myParentID [name="role"]');`

This will select only the `role` input inside `#myParentID`.